# xpath syntax for grabbing text data after a strong tag containing header text

Tags: xpath

```
<li><strong>Movie Title:</strong> Training Day</li>
```

How do I grab the textual content in this li tag; "Training Day"?

So I need to say 'if the strong tag has 'Movie Title' in it, return 'Training Day'.

I have tried stuff using the "following-sibling", but don't seem to be able to get this right.

Another attempt was

```
//li/text()[preceding::strong[contains(text(),'Movie Title')]]
```

But this returns ALL text, not just what is inside the li class.

Comment: Show how you tried to solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I grab the textual content in this li tag; "Training Day"?
>   So I need to say 'if the strong tag has 'Movie Title' in it, return 'Training Day'.

The following XPath expression selects **all** li-element's text-nodes following a strong-element which value contains the string 'Movie Title'.

```
//li[contains(strong,'Movie Title')]/strong/following-sibling::text()
```

In your example XML this results in 'Training Day'.
But if more text-nodes followed, you'd have to restrict the expression to **the first** text-node like this

```
//li[contains(strong,'Movie Title')]/strong/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `//li/text()` should return "Training Day", while `//li//text()`- both "Training Day" and "Movie Title:"

You can try more specific `XPath`

```
//li[starts-with(., "Movie Title:")]//text()[not(parent::strong)]
```

to get "Training Day" only

Comment: Hi, the problem with this is it grabs EVERY other li class contents on the page. Sorry, I should have provided more of an example I guess. I need to grab info from several divs, so need to specify the content of the strong tag each time. We have, "movie title", 'Movie Duration" etc etc too

Comment: How about `//li[starts-with(., "Movie Title:")]//text()[not(parent::strong)]`?